# Can I somehow code dynamic "macros" that calls elisp code when I type certain things in a text-mode (or org-mode) buffer?

Tags: completion, abbrev

**Short version**

When I, in the middle of a text-mode or org-mode buffer, type a line that looks like this:

```
>1d6
```

... I want Emacs to generate a random number between 1 and 6, and insert it on the following line.

**Long version**

I want to write a story in Emacs, that's based on me playing a solo table-top roleplaying game where I as the narrator make some of the decisions about what happens in the story, but I also want dice to play an important part, such as in combat. I want the dice rolls to be visible in the text - more specifically, I want to be able to type a command on a line of its own in the text-mode or org-mode buffer, which, when I type enter, calls elisp code that inserts text. I realize I can just roll ordinary physical dice at my desk and write down the results, but where's the fun in that?

To illustrate what I mean, I want to be able to write something like this:

```
Erduwin the fighter reaches the door, and as he tries to push it open,
realizes that it is stuck. In order to force it open, he has to 
perform a Strength check. This means that he has to roll a 12 or higher
on a d20 (a 20-sided die). Let's see what he rolls:
>d20
Result: 17
He rolls a 17, which is enough! With all his might, he pushes at the
door, which slowly squeaks open.
```

In this case, when I type ">d20 RET", I want an elisp function to be called, which generates a random number between 1 and 20, and inserts "Result: (the random number)" on the following line.

I suspect this could be accomplished with a fairly simplistic minor mode, but I don't know enough elisp to know where to start. Bonus points if I could also type something like:

```
>2d6+4
```

... and as a result, two six-sided dice would be rolled, added together with four, and the result inserted as above.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Thanks @drew, I wasn't aware of that. Looks like you've fixed the tags for me - much appreciated.

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes". There are multiple ways to achieve this. Your best approach is probably to code something in Elisp, or get someone to do it for you. The general approach for that code will be something like: look at what's immediately behind (or ahead), parse it into types and counts of dice, call a pseudo-random-number subroutine the appropriate number of times and accumulate the values returned, then format and insert the result.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks @PhilHudson. But how do I get that code to be executed when I press enter? If I "bind" that code to Enter, wouldn't that remove the "insert newline character at point" function of Enter?

Comment: Yes. You should bind it to something other than <return>, like say M-<return>, though that is used by at least two packages I know of, so maybe something else again. Having said that, you *could* bind it to <return> as long as you included code that effectively said "if it's not one of those dice things, do the ordinary insert-newline thing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [yasnippet](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/) (and probably other snippet/completion frameworks, and [`abbrev-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode)).

Once `yasnippet` is installed, you can [create a new snippet](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html) from your chosen mode by doing `M-x yas-new-snippet` and define a snippet template that looks like:

```text
# key: 1d6
# name: 1d6
# --
six-sided die, and the result was: `(+ 1 (random 6))` $0
```

From top down in this simple template we have:

- **key** -- the abbreviation that the snippet fires on
- **name** -- an arbitrary name (I'm not creative)
- **--** -- the end of the "header"

The remainder of the file is the replacement for the **key**. The contents of  the backticks is `eval`-able elisp, and the `$0` is where the `point` (your cursor) will be after expansion.

Taking into account our example template, and `yasnippet`'s default settings, if we have the text (with the `|` representing your cursor):

```text
and so I rolled a 1d6|
```

and I hit the `TAB` key, "1d6" will get expanded into (again, the pipe is your cursor):

```text
and so I rolled a six-sided die, and the result was: 4 |
```

I can see how using `TAB` all the time when writing prose can get quickly tiresome, so you might want to [redefine the trigger key](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-expansion.html#org87a6f68) with something like the following from the docs:

```lisp
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
;; Bind `SPC' to `yas-expand' when snippet expansion available (it
;; will still call `self-insert-command' otherwise).
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "SPC") yas-maybe-expand)
```

This is obviously just an example, but `yasnippet` is quite powerful/flexible and the documentation is rather good.

---

For reference my `yasnippet` configuration is:

```lisp
(use-package yasnippet
  :config
  (add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/snippets"))
  (yas-global-mode 1))

;; default snippets are in a separate package
(use-package yasnippet-snippets
  :requires yasnippet)
```

Comment: This is very useful, thank you.